# Crystal Report--> Running a subreport for list of external parameters

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a sub report that provides sales generated by a given person:

```
Person XXX

Item Name    Items Sold
A4 .............. 10
A6 ............... 8
A7 ............... 6
```

I want to modify this report to generate a single page report for a list of sales persons to be passed through the main report.

My question is how does one setup such report. I am not sure about which options to use while specifying the parameters for the main report.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Unlinked Subreports. Please find below the detail

http://resources.businessobjects.com/support/communitycs/TechnicalPapers/scr_subreports.pdf

Answer (score 0):

pass the variable(s) needed into the sub report (site/location,employee number, start date, end date, etc.)
Set up the sub report something like this:

```
<Report Header a> Person XXX 
<Report Header b> Item Name    Items Sold
<Group Header #1> (suppress)
<Group Footer #1> A4 ............. 10
<Group Footer #1> A6 .............  8
<Group Footer #1> A7 ............. 16
<Report Footer>   (suppress)
```

The group would be the Item Name
Items sold is a running total field

```
Field to Summarize: Item Name
Type of summary: count (not distinct count)
Evaluate: for each record
Reset: On change of group
```